# launch native Facebook app others than using fbid

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I'm develop an objective-c application which allow to open Facebook link in Facebook app, I try the following and its working fine,

```
NSString *appURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://profile/%@", fbid];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appURL]];
```

since we are using dynamic fb link so that we can't get the fbid programmatically.

May I know whether there is any others way to open the Facebook app without using fbid?

Comment: You should not use this feature to link into the native Facebook app as it is undocumented and can change at any point in time.

Comment: i understand the consequences, possible you can give a alternative way to achieve this? i know there is an alternative by using"fb://faceweb/f?href=" and "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=%s" but i can't found any reference on it.

Answer (score 0):

Following is how I solve the problem:

1. perform a RestAPI call for the requested fb link, eg : https://www.facebook.com/shoopee.online/
2. collect the returned data.byte and store in NSString
3. the required appURL will be located on "al:ios:url" property. eg : as per my example

   > meta property="al:ios:url" content="fb://page/?id=341998816144439"
4. chop the content and store as variable "appURL"
5. then open the fbApp by the following code:
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appURL]];

Hope my solution can help others.